# Is ''The principles of psychology'' by ''William James'' outdated?

Tags: psychology, history-of-psychology

I was reading about eminent psychologists and I came across William James and a book that he has written: *The Principles of Psychology*. However, [Wikipedia states this book is outdated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Principles_of_Psychology):

> Philosopher Helmut R. Wagner writes that most of the book's contents
>   are now outdated, but that it still contains insights of interest.

The article referenced is the following:

Wagner, Helmut R. (1983). Phenomenology of Consciousness and Sociology of the Life-world: An Introductory Study. Edmonton: The University of Alberta Press. p. 218. ISBN 0-88864-032-3.

Is this true or is it still worth reading?

Comment: Now that you have incorporated the context you are basing yourself on (the Wikipedia reference), it becomes even more clear your question is primarily opinion-based, or at a minimum, unclear. Wikipedia does not even state it is not worth reading ... Why does the opinion stated on wikipedia not answer your question? _**"but that it still contains insights of interest."**_ Have you looked up the referenced paper, which might in fact answer your question? In case you are interested in something more specific, you need to make your question more specific as well.

Comment: I didn't mean to make this question complicated.simply I asked about your opinions about this book. It is opinion-based.  I wanted to read this book but as soon as I saw It's 1400 pages I decided to have your opinion about whether this book is outdated or this is a good introductory book to read.

Comment: That is understandable. :) However, that is the reason this question was put on hold. I recommend you to read [the faq](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out more about why such questions are discouraged on Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [review](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R1HCBOZM66IGEM/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_viewpnt?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B008TVFCXC#R1HCBOZM66IGEM) 
Reference "Joseph C. Hager, Ph.D." Amazon Review -

> Why would anyone want to read a book about psychology that was first
>   published 113 years ago? One answer is the rationale for reading any
>   psychology book: that it provides insights into psychological issues
>   not available elsewhere. Although many psychologists of the late 19th
>   and early 20th century probably started their career by reading this
>   book, it is not appropriate today as an introduction to psychology.
>   Too many of James's viewpoints are antiquated, and his facts, outdated
>   or incorrect. Neither is it the book to read if you are looking for
>   contemporary psychological views or a compilation of psychological
>   knowledge. Recent textbooks are better for these purposes. Yet, the
>   word most frequently used to describe James's Principles of Psychology
>   is probably 'monumental' and rightly so because not only is this a
>   lengthy work (~1400pgs), but it also is the culmination of a long line
>   of philosophical thinking about the Soul, Self, Mind, Matter, and
>   related topics that began with the pre-Socratic Greeks and continued
>   through the 19th century, when positivist philosophers and
>   experimentalists began to explore psychologically relevant
>   philosophical questions in more concrete terms, invoking a scientific
>   method and rejecting metaphysics. At the end of the 19th century, a
>   seeming riot of discussion about the meaning of life, the nature of
>   consciousness, mind, ego, evolution, and related subjects dominated
>   the scientific and popular culture. At this point in history, William
>   James, an American trained as a physician and employed as a Harvard
>   professor, examines the various philosophies of the previous two
>   millenia, picking out those aspects relevant to psychology, comparing
>   and sorting them to reveal their value as unambiguous theories that
>   might be tested by research, and reflecting on how the evidence stacks
>   up in their favor. He also advances his own, original conceptions on
>   various issues. His work is not the first to collect speculation and
>   evidence into a coherent psychology, and there are many previous works
>   with "Psychology" in their titles, but James's efforts would galvanize
>   an American discipline of psychological science that would eventually
>   become a dominant intellectual force. James defines psychology as the
>   "Science of Mental Life" and describes the stream of consciousness as
>   "the ultimate fact for psychology." Out of his viewpoint, the school
>   of functionalism in psychology developed, where the mind is conceived
>   as a useful organ that evolves according to natural selection and
>   grows according to discoverable rules. His orientation towards
>   physiological and behavioral data eventually diminished the then
>   dominant psychological method of introspection that James himself uses
>   so frequently with great effect. Subsequent viewpoints in psychology,
>   such as behaviorism, though taking part of their inspiration from
>   functionalism, reject James's definition of psychology, so that by the
>   end of the 20th century, most psychologists with an empirical
>   orientation may call themselves "behavioral scientists," but certainly
>   not "mental scientists." Reading this book can be disconcerting,
>   perhaps because of his period style or Victorian sensibilities, or the
>   frequent, unglossed short quotes and phrases in German, French, and
>   Latin because he assumes the reader has at least these minimal
>   language skills. Perhaps also, it is because James is not only
>   conversant with the giants of philosophy and experimental technique
>   who preceeded him, but seemingly, with virtually every published
>   sentence to date bearing on the subjects of concern, and in veritable
>   fractal detail, producing a tour de force in erudition. His is not the
>   style of current psychology journals and textbooks, but fortunately he
>   does translate into English many long passages he quotes from their
>   original sources. Yet possibly the most disconcerting aspects are the
>   subjects that James raises in this book. The new mainstream psychology
>   after James rejects many topics as unsuitable - even for discussion -
>   that figure prominently in the intellectual history of philosophy and
>   psychology. James's view that the concept of Soul should be eliminated
>   in scientific works is one point on which later psychologists heartily
>   agree, but they also, to a large extent, throw out other concepts of
>   central concern to James, such as mind, emotion, will, and feeling.
>   Rare pleas by scholars with varying backgrounds (e.g., Ornstein,
>   Tomkins) urge students of psychology to revisit issues discussed by
>   James and address the larger questions contained therein, but such
>   exhorations echo mostly in halls of learning emptied by Vita
>   enhancement pressures. Renewal of interest reappears lately for some
>   of the suppressed topics, cast into such areas as cognitive psychology
>   or emotion theory, but James's idea that the mind is a core concept
>   remains foreign to virtually all contemporary psychologists, and much
>   of his emphasis seems uncomfortable from today's viewpoint. The
>   reluctance among psychologists to embrace such philosophical and
>   scientific issues concerning the mind is remarkably not shared by some
>   physicists, mathematicians, biologists, computer scientists, and other
>   scientists who in recent works have implied that psychologists may be
>   irrelevant to elucidating such issues, if not muddle-headed,
>   scientific dwarfs. This twist is ironic because psychologists restrict
>   their vocabulary and investigations partly to ape their conception of
>   these "hard-core" sciences. It is not clear whether psychology will
>   survive the choices that psychologists have made about their subject
>   matter, or whether psychology departments will inevitably be diced and
>   parsed into their appropriate slots in departments of computer
>   science, biology, medicine, statistics, and physics, but certainly,
>   the end of psychology is nearer if tomorrow's students of psychology
>   fail to study James's Principles of Psychology. James's work is the
>   jumping off point for much of what forms 20th century psychology:
>   habit, association, attention, memory, imagination, object and space
>   perception, etc. His thoughts about emotion, feelings, the self,
>   consciousness, and other topics remain important for today's
>   theoretical views. On the other hand, this work predates
>   psychoanalysis and does not include an organized account of abnormal
>   psychology, human communication, and other topics raised in most
>   elementary surveys of psychology. The context in which James puts
>   scientific psychology is probably the most important lesson of this
>   book. The Dover edition is unabridged, the only form of this work that
>   should be considered by the serious reader.